# how to stub/mock api requests from a redux-saga in cucumber features?

Tags: cucumber, redux-saga

I have a redux-saga that periodically yield call(fetch, url)

I'd like to have a cucumber feature that tests this app behaviour. Not the saga itself. I have such tests already.

I fail to understand how I could mock the fetch operation, especially since parallel sagas are also running in the app.